# Grid Layout Manager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm developing an android app  this has a recyclerView adapter with two view holder I try to make when view type is traveler set span count 1 and when view type is folder set span count 2 but always have 1 span count here is Grid layout manager I use

```
    GridLayoutManager gridLayout = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    gridLayout.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (adapter.getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_FOLDER)
                return 2;
            else
                return 1;
        }

    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayout);
```

and here is get view type in adapter

```
    @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    Object obj = data.get(position);
    if (obj instanceof Traveler)
        return TYPE_TRAVELER;
    else if (obj instanceof MainItem)
        return TYPE_FOLDER;

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid position " + position);
}
```

and this screenshot for the app

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDVTi.png "app_screenshot"

Comment: Please use the tag android-studio only for questions that refer to the IDE android-studio

Comment: @ConstantinBeer sorry for that